# The module '/var/task/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Release/xmljs.node'\nwas compiled against a different Node. version 93.This version of Node.js 108

Tags: node.js, xml, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, libxml-js

Some Context here: I am using aws amplify and installed a node package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxmljs` into a lambda, and getting the following error.
I already tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json and verified both lambda runtime and the local machine got version 18.

The module '/var/task/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Release/xmljs.node'\nwas compiled against a different Node.js version using\nNODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires\nNODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. Please try re-compiling or re-installing\nthe module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).",
"code": "ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED",